# Web stalker has purchased a domain name that uses my personal name, web page is defamatory

Tags: domains

We have been unsuccessful in persuading a stalker's website host to release the domain name he purchased which is my own personal name, e.g., PERSONALNAME.com. You will find my name below in the signature area. Look for yourself.

On the one page that this domain name leades to is dreadful and defamatory material. No attorney has felt it worth their time to chase this issue down, and we cannot afford to go to a national or international dispute resolution group to bring this issue to WHOIS.

Worse, the stalker is amoral and a psychopath: he would just love the attention. We've even consider trying to find someone to illegally hack into the webpage to at least redirect the domain pointers to my own professional website.

This issue has continued now for two years and is affecting my professional reputations as potential clients have looked for me online.

Is there any remedy? Your help and advice would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Contact your local bar association, they have lawyers who can help for free.

Comment: You might also want to take it up with [their hosting company](http://1and1.com): section 8 of their [General Terms and Conditions](http://order.1and1.com/Gtc?__lf=Static&linkOrigin=Hosting&linkId=ft.nav.tandc) has some subsections (e.g. 8.9 and 8.11) that a "stalker" site might be violating.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked an [ICANN's](http://www.icann.org/en/help/dndr) dispute resolution policies, there is little doubt that you would win a dispute given the content on the site.

At minimum ask friends to help you out by reporting the youtube video for bullying, which it clearly is (i've flagged it for you, but the more people the better).

Absent going to ICANN there is little you can do without employing a friendly hacker, though from the sound of the bloke he might just sue you for doing it so be careful.

You could also purchase similar domains and attempt to push that page out of the first page of the search index with better, more relevant content.

You can request general [content removal or cache updates from Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals) where a page has been changed or removed, or request [Google change it's index for other legal reasons such as defamation (which would be apt in this case)](http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1114905&page=ts.cs). I've used the first link recently and had some success, so they do respond to requests, but it may take a while for a defamation case as it's legally grey territory.

According to this recent article from Ars Technica ['A company's quest to fix online reputation without nefarious SEO'](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/03/one-companys-quest-to-fix-online-reputationwithout-nefarious-seo.ars) there are online reputation services like [brandyourself.com](https://brandyourself.com/) which can help you to repair this damage without spending the earth or resorting to black hat techniques.

My sympathy, the bloke sounds like a nightmare!

Comment: You can do a lot of things to make your stalker's life pretty difficult. If you get a pretty big team of people, volume of anything will have an effect. Facebook, youtube, Google's SERP (Search Engine Results Page)... reporting with enough numbers will atleast get it suspended for review. Spamming email with junk, etc. All of this is legal, though not necessarily moral. You could also try a WHOIS lookup to get an address or atleast email address. Traceroute will let you know the server IP where it is located and a few stops along the way, which you could do loads with just an IP.

Comment: Thank you everyone for thoughtful and sensible advice. We will follow through! - Deborah

Comment: To report to you all--including John Conde!--that YouTube has removed both videos and that we are on to an appeal to the better angels of ICANN via their stateside dispute mediators. THANK YOU! - Deborah, Lake Superior's North Shore, Minnesota USA

Comment: @DeborahMorse-Kahn Great news about the video! I recently came across this link, which may help you get defamatory content removed from search results http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?hl=en&ts=1114905&page=ts.cs

Comment: @DeborahMorse-Kahn Found an interesting article on Ars which relates to your situation, details above.